# how to send JSON object to java controller using ajax?

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, httprequest

I want to send js object to java controller and to receivce with @RequestParam anotation.

Javascript

```
(function(){

    var testVO = {
        member1 : 'hello',
        member2 : 'world'
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : 'myurl.do',
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify({
            testVO : testVO
        }),
        success : function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
})();
```

Java Controller

```
@RequestMapping("myurl.do")
@ResponseBody
public Object test3(@RequestBody TestVO testVO)
{
    return testVO;
}
```

Java TestVO Class

```
public class TestVO
{
    private String member1;
    private String member2;

    public String getMember1()
    {
        return member1;
    }

    public void setMember1(String member1)
    {
        this.member1 = member1;
    }

    public String getMember2()
    {
        return member2;
    }

    public void setMember2(String member2)
    {
        this.member2 = member2;
    }

    public MMMooVO getMamamoo()
    {
        return mamamoo;
    }
}
```

I want to map js object to Java object.
For example, js's testVO object to Java's TestVO object with annotation.
How to set controller's annotation to map??

What is right in @RequestParam("testVO") and @RequestBody??
I'm confusing.... please help.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to send data to server we would suggest to **use POST not Get ajax request**.

`GET` is mainly used to get data from server.

`@RequestBody` annotation maps the `HttpRequest` body to a transfer or domain object.

HTTP `GET` don't have request body it sends data in the header or URLparams